# Angular 8: Dynamically set formControlName in html based on component

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

In db table, I have "key_name" which is successfully returning in API and working great.

What I want to do is to set those fields value as a `formControlName` in html and in component I am using the reactive form so I have tried `formArrayName`.

Based on the change event I am pushing new `formControl` in `categoryArray` and assigning its key as db field's value.

here is my Html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <div formArrayName="categoryArray" *ngFor="let type of types; let k = index">
                                <div [formGroupName]="k">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select {{ type.cat_name }}</label>
                                        <select class="form-control custom-select" 
                                            (change)="onChangeType($event.target.value)"
                                            formControlName="{{ type.key_name }}" >
                                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                            <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.category_id">
                                                {{type.cat_name}}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

component.ts:

```
onChangeCategory(id) {
    if(id) {
      this.artistService.fetchTypeAndSubTypes(id).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.types = res.data

          this.addInNewCategory(this.types)

        }
      })
    } else {
      this.types = null
      this.subTypes = null
    }
  }

  get category(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.uploadArtWorkForm.controls.categoryArray;
  }

  addInNewCategory(types) {
    let obj = {}

    types.forEach(element => {
      obj[element['key_name']] = [null, [Validators.required]]
    });

    console.log("obj", obj)
    this.category.push(
      this.formBuilder.group(obj)   
    );

  }
```

What I want to archive is that based on 1st category selection all 2nd level category will be shown as a dynamic HTML dropdown who has their child category listing in the dropdown.

Errors that I am getting:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'categoryArray -> 1'

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'categoryArray -> 1 -> metal'
```

**EDIT:**
After setting up form control name, How can I set each newly created dropdown's value ? I need to fetch it from the db.

Here is Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dyncamic-populating-dropdown

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you create a stackblitz instance of your issue?

Comment: @Prince Not possible

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Why is not possible to create a stackblitz if you want people to help you?

Comment: @trungk18 added stackblitz

Comment: @Prince added stackblitz

Comment: Thanks, but the URL is not working. Could you please check?

Comment: @trungk18 Please check I have updated.

Comment: It is working now. I just want to double check two things.
1. After select the category, basically you want to dynamically render the other three dropdown list (Type, metal and gem). And the value of these dropdown list will be fetched from API using the category id? 
2. What is the form value that you want to get at the end after select all 4 dropdown?

Comment: Point one is right and in form value I want all the drop-down values and before that I want validate as well.

Comment: @trungk18 any luck so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried modifying your code myself at least the errors below are fixed:

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'categoryArray -> 1'

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'categoryArray -> 1 -> metal'

But you still need to improve on your end using my solution.

> Modify your app.component.html as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadArtWorkForm" (ngSubmit)="addUploadArtWorkForm();">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Category:</label>
      <select class="form-control custom-select" formControlName="cat_id" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': uploadArtWorkForm.controls['cat_id'].invalid && (uploadArtWorkForm.controls['cat_id'].dirty || uploadArtWorkForm.controls['cat_id'].touched || isFormSubmitted) }" (change)="onChangeCategory($event, $event.target.value)">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let category of parentCategories" [value] ="category.category_id">
            {{category.cat_name}}
        </option>
      </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="uploadArtWorkForm.controls['cat_id'].errors">
                <div *ngIf="uploadArtWorkForm.controls['cat_id'].errors.required">Category is
                    required.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" formArrayName="categoryArray" *ngIf="uploadArtWorkForm.get('categoryArray')['controls'].length > 0">
        <div  *ngFor="let item of uploadArtWorkForm.get('categoryArray')['controls']; let k = index">
            <div [formGroup]="item">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Select {{ types[k].cat_name }}</label>
                    <select class="form-control custom-select" [class]="types[k].key_name" (change)="onChangeType($event.target.value)" formControlName="{{ types[k].key_name }}" *ngIf="types[k].cat_name == 'Type'"> 
              <option value="">-- Select --</option>
              <option *ngFor="let type of catTypeValue" [value]="type.category_id">
                  {{type.cat_name}}
              </option>
          </select>
          <select class="form-control custom-select" [class]="types[k].key_name" (change)="onChangeType($event.target.value)" formControlName="{{ types[k].key_name }}" *ngIf="types[k].cat_name == 'Metal'">
              <option value="">-- Select --</option>
              <option *ngFor="let type of catMetalValue" [value]="type.category_id">
                  {{type.cat_name}}
              </option>
          </select>
          <select class="form-control custom-select" [class]="types[k].key_name" (change)="onChangeType($event.target.value)" formControlName="{{ types[k].key_name }}" *ngIf="types[k].cat_name == 'Gems'">
              <option value="">-- Select --</option>
              <option *ngFor="let type of catGemsValue" [value]="type.category_id">
                  {{type.cat_name}}
              </option>
          </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> and app.component.ts as below:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  uploadArtWorkForm: any;
  uploadArtWorkForm1: any;
  isFormSubmitted: boolean = false;

  parentCategories = [
    {"parent_id":0,"cat_name":"Jewelry","category_id":1},
    {"parent_id":0,"cat_name":"Painting","category_id":16},
    {"parent_id":0,"cat_name":"Photograph","category_id":22}];
  types;
  subTypes;

  //below value will be displayed in Select Type dropdown
  catTypeValue = [
    {"parent_id":2,"cat_name":"Anklets","category_id":3,"key_name":"anklets"},
    {"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Body",
    "category_id":4,
    "key_name":"body"},
    {"parent_id":2,"cat_name":"Bracelets","category_id":5,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Charms","category_id":6,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,"cat_name":"Necklaces","category_id":7,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,"cat_name":"Ornamental","category_id":8,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Rings & Studs","category_id":9,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Jewelry Metal","category_id":10,"key_name":""},{"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Yellow Gold","category_id":11,
    "key_name":""},
    {"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"White Gold","category_id":12,"key_name":"whitegold"},{"parent_id":2,
    "cat_name":"Silver","category_id":13,"key_name":"silver"}
    ]

  // below values will be displayed in Select Metal dd
  catMetalValue = [
    {"parent_id":14,"cat_name":"White Gold","category_id":24,"key_name":"whitegold"},
    {"parent_id":14,"cat_name":"Yellow Gold","category_id":24,"key_name":"whitegold"},
    ]

  // below values will be displayed in Select Gems dd
  catGemsValue = [
    {"parent_id":15,"cat_name":"Blue Gems","category_id":25,"key_name":"bluegems"}
    ]

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.uploadArtWorkForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    cat_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    categoryArray: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  onChangeType(value, id){
    console.log(value)
// solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315779/angular-8-not-getting-selected-dropdown-values-in-component-using-reactive-form?noredirect=1&lq=1
  }
  onChangeCategory(event, id) {
    if (id) {
      this.types = [
        {"parent_id":1,
        "cat_name":"Type",
        "category_id":2,
        "key_name":"type"},
        {"parent_id":1,
        "cat_name":"Metal",
        "category_id":14,
        "key_name":"metal"},
        {"parent_id":1,
        "cat_name":"Gems",
        "category_id":15,
        "key_name":"gems"}];
      if(this.uploadArtWorkForm.controls['categoryArray'].length > 0){
        this.uploadArtWorkForm.controls['categoryArray'].controls.length = 0
      }
      this.addInNewCategory(this.types);
    } else {
      this.types = null;
      this.subTypes = null;
    }
  }

  get category(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.uploadArtWorkForm.controls['categoryArray'];
  }

  addInNewCategory(types) {['categoryArray'];
    types.forEach((element, i) => {
      this.category.push(this.formBuilder.group({[element["key_name"]]: new FormControl(element["key_name"])
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this will also fix  for solution you have asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315779/angular-8-not-getting-selected-dropdown-values-in-component-using-reactive-form?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1):

Try Below,

Suppose you are getting from keys in **formKeys** Object

```
let formObj={};
Object.keys(this.formKeys||[]).forEach(d=>{
 formObj[k]=["",Validators.required];
});

this.dynamicForm=this.fb.group(formObj);
```

In html:

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicForm">
<div *ngFor="let key of ArrayOfFormKey">
  <input [fromControlName]="key">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What you are suggesting is good, How can I fetch each newly created dropdown's value and show it in their respective dropdown ?